# How one calls temporal changes of chemical content due to nuclear reactions?

Tags: nuclear-chemistry

So, I am trying to find the term for subject question: temporal change of chemical content due to nuclear reactions. Specifically, I am interested in time evolution of the number of atoms of each isotope in, let say, spontaneous decay chain but without any interest in potential chemical compounds. I was googling for "stoichiometry dynamics" and "nuclear chemistry kinetics" but these seem to have specific meaning clearly distinct from what I had in mind.

Comment: Do you know the Szilard-Chalmers effect ? It happens when a stable isotope is bombarded with neutrons to produce a radioactive isotope emitting gamma rays. In the gamma-ray emission, the recoil is sufficient to break a chemical bond existing with this isotope. For example, if  $\ce{NaClO3}$ is hit by neutrons, the stable isotope $\ce{Cl-35}$ is transformed into $\ce{Cl-36}$, which emits gamma rays. This atom is pushed out of the chlorate ion and can be recognize by adding $\ce{AgNO3}$ in the solution : this produces a precipitate of $\ce{AgCl}$.  The fate of the 3 oxygen atoms is not known.

Comment: Maybe “radioactive nuclei decay kinetics”?

Comment: @Maurice - I wasn't aware of this specific effect, but something along these lines. This is more of a "singular" transformation, I had in mind for an example decay of U-235 where you have rich dynamics, cascade of decays described by a Batemans equation.  I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel if there is nomenclature for this.

Comment: @Andrew - yeah that could work. Basically, difference between dynamics and kinetics is that dynamics goes into specifics of the cause of the temporal change, but kinetics just describes time evolution. Just wanted to check if there is an established nomenclature.

Comment: Does "transmutation" not serve your purposes?

Comment: Well, depends how you see it - transmutation is, by my understanding, the very nuclear reaction that changes Z and A in the nucleus. Such events take place in very short period and are stochastic in its quantum nature. Like I (unsuccessfully?!) explained, I was more interested in meso-temporal regime where such individual events are not observed but the whole process can be described with smooth, derivable functions.

Comment: Isn't decay what are you looking for???